# Could not dispatch event

Tags: android, dispatchevent

When I run my app locally it runs but when I want to broadcast it I get the following errors and I don't know why?

> 10-16 09:53:46.114 5990-5990/? E/Event: Could not dispatch event: class com.bakerframework.baker.events.DownloadManifestCompleteEvent to subscribing class class com.bakerframework.baker.model.RemoteIssueCollection
>   10-16 09:53:46.114 5990-5990/? E/Event: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-16 09:53:46.114 5990-5990/? E/Event:     at com.bakerframework.baker.model.RemoteIssueCollection.processJson(RemoteIssueCollection.java:197)

```
package com.bakerframework.baker.events;

public class DownloadManifestCompleteEvent {

    public DownloadManifestCompleteEvent() {
    }
}    

public class RemoteIssueCollection implements IssueCollection {

private final HashMap<String, Issue> issueMap;
private List<String> categories;

private List<Sku> subscriptionSkus;

// Tasks management
private DownloadManifestJob downloadManifestJob;
private FetchPurchasesJob fetchPurchasesJob;

// Data Processing
final String JSON_ENCODING = "utf-8";
final SimpleDateFormat SDF_INPUT = new SimpleDateFormat(BakerApplication.getInstance().getString(R.string.format_input_date), Locale.US);
final SimpleDateFormat SDF_OUTPUT = new SimpleDateFormat(BakerApplication.getInstance().getString(R.string.format_output_date), Locale.US);

// Categories
public static final String ALL_CATEGORIES_STRING = "All Categories";

// Billing
@NonNull
private Inventory inventory;

public RemoteIssueCollection() {
    // Initialize issue map
    issueMap = new HashMap<>();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

public List<String> getCategories() {
    return categories;
}

public List<Sku> getSubscriptionSkus() {
    return subscriptionSkus;
}

public List<String> getIssueProductIds() {
    List<String> issueProductIdList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Issue issue : getIssues()) {
        if(issue.getProductId() != null && !issue.getProductId().equals("")) {
            issueProductIdList.add(issue.getProductId());
        }
    }
    return issueProductIdList;
}

public List<Issue> getIssues() {
    if(isLoading() || issueMap == null) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }else{
        return new ArrayList<>(issueMap.values());
    }
}

public Issue getIssueBySku(Sku sku) {
    return getIssueByProductId(sku.id);
}

public Issue getIssueByProductId(String productId) {
    for(Issue issue : getIssues()) {
        if(issue.getProductId() != null && issue.getProductId().equals(productId)) {
            return issue;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public boolean isLoading() {
    return (downloadManifestJob != null && !downloadManifestJob.isCompleted()) || (fetchPurchasesJob != null && !fetchPurchasesJob.isCompleted());
}

// Reload data from backend
public void load() {
    if (!isLoading()) {
        if (BakerApplication.getInstance().isNetworkConnected()) {
            // Online Mode: Reload issue collection
            downloadManifestJob = new DownloadManifestJob(Configuration.getManifestUrl(), getCachedFile());
            BakerApplication.getInstance().getJobManager().addJobInBackground(downloadManifestJob);
        }else if(isCacheAvailable()) {
            processManifestFile(getCachedFile());
        }else{
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new IssueCollectionErrorEvent(new Exception("No cached file available")));
        }
    }
}

public void processManifestFileFromCache() {

}

private void processManifestFile(File file)  {

    try {

        // Create issues
        processJson(FileHelper.getJsonArrayFromFile(file));

        // Process categories
        categories = extractAllCategories();

        // you only need this if this activity needs information about purchases/SKUs
        if(BakerApplication.getInstance().isNetworkConnected()) {
            inventory = BakerApplication.getInstance().getCheckout().loadInventory();
            inventory.whenLoaded(new InventoryLoadedListener());
            inventory.load();
        }

        // Instantly trigger load event
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new IssueCollectionLoadedEvent());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "processing error (invalid json): " + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "processing error (buffer error): " + e);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "processing error (parse error): " + e);
    }

}

private void processJson(final JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException, ParseException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    JSONObject json;
    JSONArray jsonCategories;
    List<String> categories;
    List<String> issueNameList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Loop through issues
    int length = jsonArray.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        json = new JSONObject(jsonArray.getString(i));

        // Get issue data from json
        String issueName = jsonString(json.getString("name"));
        String issueProductId = json.isNull("product_id") ? null : jsonString(json.getString("product_id"));
        String issueTitle = jsonString(json.getString("title"));
        String issueInfo = jsonString(json.getString("info"));
        String issueDate = jsonDate(json.getString("date"));
        Date issueObjDate = jsonObjDate(json.getString("date"));
        String issueCover = jsonString(json.getString("cover"));
        String issueUrl = jsonString(json.getString("url"));
        int issueSize = json.has("size") ? json.getInt("size") : 0;

        Issue issue;
        if(issueMap.containsKey(issueName)) {
            // Get issue from issue map
            issue = issueMap.get(issueName);
            // Flag fields for update
            if(!issue.getCover().equals(issueCover)) {
                issue.setCoverChanged(true);
            }
            if(!issue.getUrl().equals(issueUrl)) {
                issue.setUrlChanged(true);
            }
        }else{
            // Create new issue and store in issue map
            issue = new Issue(issueName);
            issueMap.put(issueName, issue);
        }

        // Set issue data
        issue.setTitle(issueTitle);
        issue.setProductId(issueProductId);
        issue.setInfo(issueInfo);
        issue.setDate(issueDate);
        issue.setObjDate(issueObjDate);
        issue.setCover(issueCover);
        issue.setUrl(issueUrl);
        issue.setSize(issueSize);

        // Set categories
        if(json.has("categories")) {
            jsonCategories = json.getJSONArray("categories");
            categories = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < jsonCategories.length(); j++) {
                categories.add(jsonCategories.get(j).toString());
            }
            issue.setCategories(categories);
        }else{
            issue.setCategories(new ArrayList<String>());
        }

        // Add name to issue name list
        issueNameList.add(issueName);

    }

    // Get rid of old issues that are no longer in the manifest
    for(Issue issue : issueMap.values()) {
        if(!issueNameList.contains(issue.getName())) {
            issueMap.remove(issue);
        }
    }

}

// Helpers

private String jsonDate(String value) throws ParseException {
    return SDF_OUTPUT.format(SDF_INPUT.parse(value));
}

private Date jsonObjDate(String value) throws ParseException {
    return SDF_INPUT.parse(value);
}

private String jsonString(String value) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    if(value != null) {
        return new String(value.getBytes(JSON_ENCODING), JSON_ENCODING);
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

private String getCachedPath() {
    return Configuration.getCacheDirectory() + File.separator + BakerApplication.getInstance().getString(R.string.path_shelf);
}

private File getCachedFile() {
    return new File(getCachedPath());
}

public boolean isCacheAvailable() {
    return getCachedFile().exists() && getCachedFile().isFile();
}

public void updatePrices(Inventory.Products inventoryProducts, List<String> productIds) {

    // Update google-play subscriptions
    if(inventoryProducts != null) {
        boolean hasSubscription = false;
        subscriptionSkus = new ArrayList<>();
        final Inventory.Product subscriptionProductCollection = inventoryProducts.get(SUBSCRIPTION);
        if (subscriptionProductCollection.supported) {
            for (Sku sku : subscriptionProductCollection.getSkus()) {
                subscriptionSkus.add(sku);
            }
        }

        // Update google-play purchased issues
        final Inventory.Product inAppProductCollection = inventoryProducts.get(IN_APP);
        if (inAppProductCollection.supported) {
            // Update issue prices
            for (Sku sku : inAppProductCollection.getSkus()) {
                Issue issue = getIssueBySku(sku);
                if(issue != null) {
                    // Check for subscription
                    issue.setPurchased(inAppProductCollection.isPurchased(sku));
                    issue.setSku(sku);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error: " + R.string.err_purchase_not_possible);
        }
    }

    // Update backend-purchased issues
    if(productIds != null) {
        for (String productId : productIds) {
            Issue issue = getIssueByProductId(productId);
            if(issue != null) {
                issue.setPurchased(true);
            }
        }
    }
}

public List<String> extractAllCategories() {

    // Collect all categories from issues
    List<String> allCategories = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Issue issue : issueMap.values()) {
        for(String category : issue.getCategories()) {
            if(allCategories.indexOf(category) == -1) {
                allCategories.add(category);
            }
        }
    }

    // Sort categories
    Collections.sort(allCategories);

    // Append all categories item
    allCategories.add(0, ALL_CATEGORIES_STRING);

    return allCategories;
}


public List<Issue> getDownloadingIssues() {
    List<Issue> downloadingIssues = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Issue issue : issueMap.values()) {
        if(issue.isDownloading()) {
            downloadingIssues.add(issue);
        }
    }
    return downloadingIssues;
}

public void cancelDownloadingIssues(final List<Issue> downloadingIssues) {
    for (Issue issue : downloadingIssues) {
        if(issue.isDownloading()) {
            issue.cancelDownloadJob();
        }
    }
}

public Issue getIssueByName(String issueName) {
    return issueMap.get(issueName);
}

private class InventoryLoadedListener implements Inventory.Listener {
    @Override
    public void onLoaded(@NonNull Inventory.Products inventoryProducts) {
        // Load existing purchases from backend
        fetchPurchasesJob = new FetchPurchasesJob(Configuration.getManifestUrl());
        BakerApplication.getInstance().getJobManager().addJobInBackground(fetchPurchasesJob);
        }
    }

    // @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public void onEventMainThread(DownloadManifestCompleteEvent event) {
        processManifestFile(getCachedFile());
    }

    // @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public void onEventMainThread(DownloadManifestErrorEvent event) {
        Log.i("IssueCollection", "DownloadManifestErrorEvent");
        if(isCacheAvailable()) {
            processManifestFile(getCachedFile());
        }else{
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new IssueCollectionErrorEvent(new Exception("No cached file available")));
        }
    }

    // @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public void onEventMainThread(FetchPurchasesCompleteEvent event) {

        // Set purchased issues
        updatePrices(inventory.getProducts(), event.getFetchPurchasesResponse().issues);

        // Trigger issues loaded event
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new IssueCollectionLoadedEvent());

    }


    // @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public void onEventMainThread(FetchPurchasesErrorEvent event) {

        // Set purchased issues
        updatePrices(inventory.getProducts(), null);

        // Trigger issues loaded event
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new IssueCollectionLoadedEvent());

    }

    public Inventory getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }

}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.bakerframework.baker" android:versionCode="10" android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!--^permission_c2d--><permission android:name="com.magloft.demo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" /><!--$permission_c2d-->
<!--^uses_permission_c2d--><uses-permission android:name="com.magloft.demo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /><!--$uses_permission_c2d-->

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    android:vmSafeMode="true"
    android:allowClearUserData="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:name=".BakerApplication">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ShelfActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/custom_actionbar">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.IssueActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.ShelfActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.InfoActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.ShelfActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.bakerframework.baker.settings.SettingsActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.ShelfActivity"
        android:theme="@style/custom_actionbar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ModalActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.IssueActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <!--^gcm_category_name--><category android:name="com.magloft.demo" /><!--$gcm_category_name-->
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

can you help me please. if you need anything else i can give you more informations.

Comment: whai is line no 197 in ..RemoteIssueCollection.java:

Comment: int length = jsonArray.length(); ----197
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { ----198
            json = new JSONObject(jsonArray.getString(i));----199

Comment: i think you are getting null jsonArray ... check it.

Comment: it is a github project from baker so i dont know where exactly i should paste my json url !! can i upload the project so you might help me???

Comment: naaahhh.... you should do it yourself. why someone else should do your homework ?

Comment: ok you are right thanks i will try to solve it !! the thing is that i have a deadline and solved the problem to run it local but i have to solve the problem for broadcast too thats why i posted my question here ! but anyways thanks a lot for your quick help

Comment: yess... you can do :) ..just try to understand the flow of project. and it will be done. try to figure where you are calling the `processJson` method in your code.. and check the URL and result what you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

if you open the proguard,you should add below rules on your proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class your package name.template.bean.** {*;}
-keep class your package name.wxapi.bean.** {*;}
-keep class de.greenrobot.event.** {*;}
-keepclassmembers,includedescriptorclasses class ** {
     public void onEvent*(**);`enter code here`
     void onEvent*(**);
}

#all the beans you post with eventbus.post
```

hope can help you